# How to load a custom location in Cordova+Ember when user click on system notification?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ember.js

I have an app made in Cordova using Ember framework.

When I receive a system notification I want to open a custom location based on id that notification send me. Notification call a method out of Ember route/controller system.

How I can call a ember router to load a custom location based on notification id if the method are not inside Ember managed code?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Ember.Instrumentation module which can be used for such scenarios.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html

To send an event from outside Ember:

```
Ember.Instrumentation.instrument("eventGroup.notificationOccured", {id: 'id_which_you_got_from_notification'});
```

To subscribe the event inside Ember code:

```
Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("eventGroup.notificationOccured", {
      before: function(id, timestamp, payload) {
        // Here you can do routing
      },
      after: function() {}
});
```

The `subscribe` can be inside Ember App codebase where you can `transitionTo` the route depending on the id.

You can probably put the subscribe code snippet in your IndexRoute's `setupController` or inside any controller method which would have already executed whenever notification arrives.

In case you want to put the code in controller then redirection can happen via `controller.transitionToRoute(routeName);`

Comment: How I can routing on before method? this.transitionTo? Where must I set the subscribe?

Comment: Cool!! Great that it worked for you :) Nice to hear about Ember being used wrapped inside Cordova.

Comment: How do I run the `Ember.Instrumentation.instrument();` code from outside ember?